# Loading Analyze 7.5 format images in python

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I'm doing some work whereby I have to load an manipulate CT images in a format called the [Analyze 7.5 file format](http://eeg.sourceforge.net/ANALYZE75.pdf).

Part of this manipulation - which takes absolutely ages with large images - is loading the raw binary data to a numpy array and reshaping it to the correct dimensions. Here is an example:

```
headshape = (512,512,245) # The shape the image should be
headdata = np.fromfile("Analyze_CT_Head.img", dtype=np.int16) # loads the image as a flat array, 64225280 long. For testing, a large array of random numbers would do

head_shaped = np.zeros(shape=headshape) # Array to hold the reshaped data

# This set of loops is the problem
for ux in range(0, headshape[0]):
    for uy in range(0, headshape[1]):
        for uz in range(0, headshape[2]):
            head_shaped[ux][uy][uz] = headdata[ux + headshape[0]*uy + (headshape[0]*headshape[1])*uz] # Note the weird indexing of the flat array - this is the pixel ordering I have to work with
```

I know numpy can do reshaping of arrays quickly, but I can't figure out the correct combination of transformations needed to replicate the effect of the nested loops.

Is there a way to replicate that strange indexing with some combination of numpy.reshape/numpy.ravel etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reshape in combination with swapaxes

```
headshape = (2,3,4) 
headdata = rand(2*3*4)

head_shaped_short = headdata.reshape(headshape[::-1]).swapaxes(0,2)
```

worked fine in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [nibabel](http://nipy.org/nibabel), a python library that implements readers/writers for the 'Analyze' format. It may have already solved this for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - nibabel looks pretty cool. I do have to deal with other formats so this may be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` stores arrays flat in the memory. The `strides` attribute contains the necessary information how to map multidimensional indices to the flat indices in the memory.

[Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray) is some further reading about `numpy`'s memory layout.

This should work for you:

```
# get the number of bytes of the specified dtype
dtype = headdata.dtype
byte_count = dtype.itemsize

headdata = headdata.reshape(headshape)
x, y, z = headshape
headdata.strides = (byte_count, byte_count * x, byte_count * x * y)

# copy data to get back to standard memory layout
data = headdata.copy()
```

The code exploits setting the `strides` attribute to reflect your custom memory mapping and to create the (hopefully) correct multidimensional array. After that, it copies the whole array into `data`, in order to get back to a standard memory layout.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I occasionally have to interface with MATLAB/Octave, so knowing they do things in fortran layout is handy!